# Dual boot 14.04 alongside Win8

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

So I'm running a fresh install of Win8 on a 60gb SSD with a another 300HDD for storage. I have set a 20gb space for the installation of Ubuntu alongside Win. The issue is when I run the DVD with Ubuntu for installation it shows that there is no other OS even though I just restarted from windows desktop... I don't have secure boot and my fast start up is turned off. Mobo is a Sabertooth 990FX R2.0

Comment: Well I'm just going to start off by getting rid of win8 this UI is horrible and not worth 3rd party fixes :/

Comment: Have you read [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835) ?

Answer (score 0):

Pleaes follow this link (http://www.crappy3.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-on-a-pc-having-windows-8-1/) and you should be able to do it yourself.

Comment: Yeah I've already done those steps. The issue is I don't have an option to install alongside Win. Ubuntu tells me there is no other OS on the computer and doesn't read the partitions that I made in windows. I've tried repair windows I've tried live USB and DVD versions of Ubuntu and it is the same thing every time.